# Word or phrase for that part of writing that ensures clarity of speaker and place

Tags: writing, dialogue

I was reading a book the other day and, at several points in the story, became very confused as to which character was talking. It would also happen that the characters would suddenly be at new locations without explanation or transition. Even though other aspects of the writing were quite entertaining, this poor scene-setting made reading the book frustrating.

Is there a word or a technical term that describes that part of writing, the nuts-and-bolts part of the prose that glues together the story and keeps the reader from confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called **[transition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_%28fiction%29)**. It is sometimes called "scene transition" also.

> Transitions in fiction are words, phrases, sentences, paragraphs, or punctuation that may be used to signal various changes in a story, including changes in time, location, point-of-view character, mood, tone, emotion, and pace.

Comment: 'And now for something completely different....'

Comment: I just realized that this term is in the question also.

Comment: Sorry, ermanen – I was just quoting perhaps the most famous / infamous / link-snubbing example I can remember, from Python. Keep quiet about the OP answering their own question and maybe nobody will notice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the **[setting](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/setting)**

> the time, place, environment, and surrounding circumstances of an event, story, play, etc

Answer (score 0):

**Continuity**.

> In fiction, continuity (also called time-scheme) is consistency of the
>   characteristics of people, plot, objects, and places seen by the
>   reader or viewer over some period of time. It is relevant to several
>   media.

([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_%28fiction%29) )